# MySQL master slave replication is pull or push?

Tags: mysql, push, replication, pull

MySQL master slave replication is pull, push or both? I encountered this question in the interview. Are there any authoritative references?

I looked it up on the Internet but didn't find the right answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here's a similar Q&A on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/273047)

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in how replication works for MySQL db …

The way it works is that all the DML operations (read insert update) will be done to master node (leader) and these changes are read (requested) by slave participants using bin log.

This concludes that MySQL replication is a push based mechanism.